# Ruby Class Module Uninitialized Constant

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a namespace for my classes in a console application.

My structure is something like the following:

lib/somemodule/class1.rb
lib/somemodule/class2.rb

Now for example I would have the following:

```
 module SomeModule
      class Class1
          def self.method1
             SomeModule::Class2.new()
          end
      end
 end

 module SomeModule
      class Class2

      end
 end
```

This would result in an error like the following: uninitialized constant SomeModule::Class2

Please advise on how to solve this problem.

Comment: How are you requiring each file?

Comment: Clearly your `lib/somemodule/class2.rb` file is not required at the moment you're calling `method1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work: simply add :: to the name of the module:

```
 module SomeModule
      class Class1
          def self.method1
             ::SomeModule::Class2.new()
          end
      end
 end
```

Comment: I didn't understand you have 2 files. I think the above comment by @Marc-André Lafortune is right. You should add a 'require' statement to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting any error? ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]